# How does PATH get its contents back after I restart the shell?

Tags: bash, paths

Exercise 2 from [Missing Semester](https://missing.csail.mit.edu/2019/shell/) asks the following:

> Run `PATH=` and try running the previous commands again, some work and some don’t, can you figure out why?

Setting `PATH=` removes all the contents from the `PATH` variable. Then `echo $PATH` yields just an empty line. But when I restart the shell, all the contents of the `PATH` variable are there again. My question is where does `PATH` variable get its values from when I restart the shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, every process inherits its *environment* (including a value for the `PATH`) from its parent. So if you start a shell from a terminal emulator, the shell inherits from the terminal which inherits from the desktop session and so on. If you follow the process tree back, you will find that a default `PATH` value is read from the `/etc/environment` file by the [pam_env](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/pam_env.8.html) module when a user's session is initiated.

*Additionally, if you are using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), path components may be inherited from the Windows host session via the `appendWindowsPath` [interoperability feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#interop-settings)*.

For the specific case of shells, the `PATH` variable may additionally be set or modified by various system-wide and/or user-specific configuration files, depending on

- which shell you are using (bash, dash, ksh, zsh, csh etc.)
- how the shell is invoked (as a login shell, as an interactive non-login shell, or as a non-interactive shell)

For bash, you can read the details in the INVOCATION section of `man bash`.

Comment: Oh, I see! Most of the values are listed in `/etc/environment`. I am using Ubuntu on WSL2, there are some additional values in `PATH` that start with `/mnt`, which are not listed there. Any idea where those come from?

Comment: @Terrarium thanks for the reminder - I have added a note about that